# The subset of $S_n$ of all permutations that leave some element in its place is a subgroup. Is it a valid example?.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I found this example in appendix A.3 of the book "A terse introduction to linear algebra".
But if you permute $\{1,2,3\}$ first keeping only $1$ fixed and then keeping only $3$ fixed, in their composition none of the elements is fixed. So looks like the elements are not closed under the composition operation. Can you point out where am I making a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange, It is bc you should keep a set of elements fixed throughout i guess

Comment: I suspect they mean 'the set of all permutations leaving some _specific_ element fixed'; e.g., 'the set of all permutations that leave 3 fixed'. If they mean 'the set of all permutations that are not [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)' then your argument is completely correct.

Comment: If the statement in the book is worded exactly like the title of your question, then your interpretation of it (which you've shown to be false) is as legitimate as the intended interpretation (which is true). Such ambiguity should not occur in mathematical writing, especially in introductory books, but I'm afraid it often does occur (and I've probably been guilty myself). An author often fails to notice ambiguity because the unintended meaning is obviously false and thus obviously unintended --- obviously to the author but maybe not to the reader.

Comment: Yeah. Fixing a particular element makes sense. It is almost like the set of all automorphisms on the Set \ {that particular element } which is a group in itself. Thank you for the responses. Still trying to figure out how to use the site though, even though already excited.

Comment: The smallest subgroup of $S_3$ containing all the permutations which fix precisely one element is, in fact, $S_3$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the book meant the subset leaving a particular element in place is a subgroup, e.g. just the permutations leaving 1 in place is a subgroup. You are correct, the set of permutations leaving any element in place is not a subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_1$ be the set of bijective correspondences between $\{1,2,3\}$ and itself such that they fix the element $1$. If $f$ and $g$ are two such permutations, then their composition obviously fixes $1$, by definition of composition of functions, and by the fact that both $f$ and $g$ are in $F_1$. Then observe that the identity function fixes $1$, because it fixes $\{1,2,3\}$. To finally assert that $F_1$ is a subgroup, you need to show that the inverse of a permutation which fixes $1$ still fixes $1$. So suppose $f$ is an element of $F_1$. And let $f^{-1}$ denote its inverse function. Suppose by contradiction that $f^{-1}$ does not fix $1$, then you get the absurd that the composition of $f$ with $f^{-1}$, which is the identity function, does not fix $1$, proving that $f^{-1}$ must be an element of $F_1$. The same for $F_n$ for all $n$, $F_i$ denoting the subset of the set of elements of the symmetric group on $n$ symbols, which fix the $i$-th symbol for every fixed $i$ between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: Yeah, assuming there is a particular set of elements fixed in all the mappings, this is the explanation. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It may worth generalizing a  little bit.

Let $A$ be a set and $B\subseteq A$. Define:

$$\operatorname{Fix}(B):=\{f\in \operatorname{Sym}(A)\mid f(b)=b, \forall b\in B\}\subseteq \operatorname{Sym}(A)$$

Let $f,f'\in \operatorname{Fix}(B)$; then, $(ff')(b)=f(f'(b))=f(b)=b, \forall b\in B$, and hence $ff'\in \operatorname{Fix}(B)$. If $\operatorname{Fix}(B)$ is finite (in particular if $A$ is finite), then the closure is enough to conclude that $\operatorname{Fix}(B)\le \operatorname{Sym}(A)$. If $\operatorname{Fix}(B)$ is infinite (then necessarily for infinite $A$), then we have to prove also the "closure by inverses": let $f\in \operatorname{Fix}(B)$; then, $\forall b \in B$, it is $b=f^{-1}(f(b))=f^{-1}(b)$, whence $f^{-1}\in \operatorname{Fix}(B)$.

Yours is the very special case: $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1\}$ $($or $B=\{2\}$, or $B=\{3\}$, or $B=\{1,2\}$, etc.$)$.

---

**Edit**

If we are allowed to appeal to action theory, then by considering the "prototypical" action of $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$ on $A$ (namely, $\sigma\cdot a:=\sigma(a)$), we get:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Fix}(B) &=\{f\in \operatorname{Sym}(A)\mid f(b)=b, \forall b\in B\} \\
&=\{f\in \operatorname{Sym}(A)\mid f\in\operatorname{Stab}(b), \forall b\in B\} \\
&=\{f\in\operatorname{Stab}(b), \forall b\in B\} \\
&= \bigcap_{b\in B}\operatorname{Stab}(b)
\end{alignat}

Since, $\operatorname{Stab}(a)\le \operatorname{Sym}(A), \forall a\in A$, we have finally $\operatorname{Fix}(B)\le \operatorname{Sym}(A)$.

Comment: Can you explain the line about Fix(B) <=  Sym(A)? Was it not defined to be a subset? How are we defining the order here? Also I didn't get the infinite part, can you refer me to some article explaining the concept?

Comment: Sure, @Agniv. There is a lemma stating that a nonempty *finite* subset of a group is a subgroup if it is closed under group's operation (see e.g. Herstein's Topics in Algebra, 2nd Ed., Lemma 2.4.2). The lemma "just upstream" of it (*ibidem*, Lemma 2.4.1) states more generally that a nonempty subset of a group is a subgroup if and only if: a) the subset is closed under group's operation; b) the inverse of each element of the subset stays in the subset ("closure by inverses").

Comment: This is clear now. Will you care to elaborate why in case of finite set, closure by inverse is not required? Will the inverse always exist because in finite group each of the element has finite order and the inverse of that element can be constructed by mutiplying the same element (order -1) times?

Comment: Well, rather than "not required", it is just implied by the closure, which then by itself suffices to the aim. Yes, it is basically as you say, but I couldn't formalize it better than as done in the quoted resource (but I'm sure that any standard textboox on algebra do the same). Note the finiteness we are here referring to is the one of $H$: so, e.g

Comment: ...to prove that $\{-1,1\}$ (finite) is a subgroup of nonzero reals (infinite!) under multiplication it's enough to prove It Is closed.

Comment: Yes. Will sure check the book out. Thank you.